# Create a maven project with parent's packaging war

Tags: maven, war, pom.xml, packaging, parentid

I want to create a Maven project. I want it to have a parent project. The problem is that the parent project has a package in: war. 
I see an error :

```
Invalid packaging for parent POM  must be "pom" but is "war"
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

A parent project (`packaging` with type `pom`) is by definition a container of submodules. Only the submodules are allowed to be of specific packaging types (like `war` or `jar`). You use a parent project to aggregate common dependencies and build configurations.

I suggest that you put the code you want to reuse in a submodule of type `jar` and then add this submodule as a dependency of other projects you have (with packaing type `war` or `jar`).

You could read [Chapter 6](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html) of the book Maven by Example where it illustrates how to build a maven multi-module project.